# How to set up a resource shared by several unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.6

In Python, how can I have one setup (which may contain expensive function calls) for a whole set of unit tests?

Example:

```
import unittest

class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print "expensive call"
    def test1(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
    def test2(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Will run the expensive call twice:

```
$ python unittest.py
expensive call
.expensive call
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

How can I change it so the expensive call is made only once and its resources accessible to all tests?

UPDATE: I'm using Python 2.6.

Comment: Are you talking about data or files? These can be written to a file and that file can be loaded by each test case.

Comment: OK, but it would be nicer not to have to involve the file system.

Comment: So in the setup that I want to do for all tests I am building a large dict (~1 million string entries). I just tried dumping it once and loading using pickle in each test, but it's very slow.

Comment: Does your code contain logic or things that only occur with 1 million entries? The obvious recommendation is making the dict smaller but if that's not possible then we'll need to keep looking for a solution.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: True, I hadn't really though of that. The unit test should probably use small toy data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use setUpClass

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print 'setUpClass'
        cls.data = 123

    def test_one(self):
        print 'test_one'
        print self.data

    def test_two(self):
        print 'test_two'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass

UPDATE:

For python 2.6, I suppose you could use class-level attributes:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
     value = result_of_some_expensive_function()
     def test(self):
         print self.value
```

That function will run once when your test is defined.

Comment: Thanks, looks nice. But I forgot to say I am forced to use Python 2.6. Is there a workaround for Python 2.6?

Comment: Ah, the class-level attributes are great for this!