# unittest setUpClass alternative for python < 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-unittest

In Python 2.7, it is possible to run class level setup in unittest.Testcase as follows:

```
class ClassName(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        print 'Some class level setup'
```

Unfortunately, I need to run some tests in Python 2.6 environment. What is the alternative for setUpClass in that version?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202085/how-to-set-up-a-resource-shared-by-several-unit-tests

Answer (score 8):

The Python 2.7 version of `unittest` is available for Python 2.6 (actually, all the way back to Python 2.3!) as the `unittest2` module on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2

Once that's installed, `setupClass` methods will work on your test classes:

```
import unittest2
class ClassName(unittest2.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print 'Some class level setup'
```